# How can I deploy my project developed with Larvel,vue with inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, installation, deployment, inertiajs

I tried several free servers, but they all give me an error when running the npm install, that the vendor vue file is not found, and so on. Anyone who has a course or a blog to do the step-by-step deployment? on any server.
In Vercel I almost did the deployment, but when I did the deployment I got this in the deployment:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/task/user/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Read-only file system The exception occurred while attempting to log: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. 
Context: {"exception":{}} in /var/task/user/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:134 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/task/user/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(44): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Object(Monolog\LogRecord)) 
#1 /var/task/user/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(379): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Object(Monolog\LogRecord)) 
#2 /var/task/user/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(671): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(Object(Monolog\Level), 'Unable to creat...', Array) 
#3 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(184): Monolog\Logger->emergency('Unable to creat...', Array) 
#4 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(61): Illuminate\Log\Logger->writeLog('emergency', 'Unable to creat...', Array) 
#5 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(142): Illuminate\Log\Logger->emergency('Unable to creat...', Array) 
#6 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(307): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->Illuminate\Log\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Log\Logger)) 
#7 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(141): tap(Object(Illuminate\Log\Logger), Object(Closure)) 
#8 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(124): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->get(NULL) 
#9 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(665): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver() 
#10 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(317): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Class "LaravelL...', Array) 
#11 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(278): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->reportThrowable(Object(Error)) 
#12 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(497): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error)) 
#13 /var/task/user/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->reportException(Object(Error)) 
#14 /var/task/user/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
#15 /var/task/user/api/index.php(3): require('/var/task/user/...') 
#16 {main} thrown in /var/task/user/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 134
```

I think it may be because the version I'm using of Vercel is the free one. I need help, and sorry for my english.

Deploy my project in laravel, I see with inertia my project url:[https://github.com/Jomay777/InfoSport-laravel-inertia-permission/tree/main]. Glitches and errors, with npm install, free versions.

Comment: witch server are you using

Answer (score 0):

As the exception depicts:

```
The stream or file "/var/task/user/storage/logs/laravel.log" 
could not be opened in append mode: 
Failed to open stream: 
Read-only file system The exception occurred while attempting to log: 
Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger.
```

The laravel application cannot write to `storage/logs/laravel.log`

The wide solution is to allow write in storage for example:

```bash
chmod a+w -R /var/task/user/storage/
```

Note that this command may need to run as sudo.